# Configure virtualenv content path instead of .venv/local/bin/activate

Tags: python, virtualenv

I don't know why but my venv files are being created in a slightly different path than usual.

It should be `.venv/bin/activate`, instead of `.venv/local/bin/activate`. This is giving me issues in other tools.

Why is it behaving this way, and how can I change it?

```
python3 -m virtualenv .venv
```

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and Python 3.10.4.

Comment: How about python3 -m venv .venv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in setuptools, source: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3278

Comment: Amazing, that explains why recreating my Ubuntu image solved my issue.